# Bathroom lights go off and come back on after a few minutes

Tags: electrical, lighting

My bathroom light from time to time goes off after being on for a few minutes then comes back on then goes off again. When I flip the switch for the light nothing happens and I have to wait for the light to come back on. Does anyone have a solution to this? Getting tired of the horror movie lights...

Comment: What type of fixture? What kind and size of bulb?  It sounds like thermal cutoff which is usually due to mismatched bulb.

Comment: Could also be a dodgy switch, or a bad ballast if fluorescent, we really need more information...

Comment: its the normal 60w household bulbs and the fixture has four lamps on it in a row not sure how to add a picture

Comment: You probably need a new bulb - go get a new bulb and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

if you have LED bulbs in a globe with no airflow, they can overheat. Many have a thermal shutdown feature that will turn off the LEDs if they get too hot. Once they cool down, the controller allows them to turn on again. This explains why flipping the power does nothing: they are still too hot.

Try a lower wattage bulb, a more expensive bulb, or a decorative tungsten bulb.

Answer (score 0):

Because it comes on when you being, and then turns off, this suggests that the connection between lamp and socket is not good. As it warms up the contacts are separating, then when it cools down they connect again. 
But if its not the bulb that's loose then it could be the wiring at the bulb socket which is loose. The second is potentially dangerous as arcing might cause a fire.

Try taking the bulb out, cleaning around the threads on the bulb and in socket (-make sure its off please). Then screw the bulb back in until firm.

If that doesn't work then you (or a friend who feels OK about it) can use a small screwdriver to ensure the screw connections on the socket are tight. No chance of electric shock if the switch is off, OK.

If the problem does not go away - sorry IMHO you'll probably need an electrician :(

Answer (score 0):

Thermal cut off is the culprit  here it happenehappened to me after i replaced the transformers  and installeinstalled the normal gud 10 globes

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please take a moment to [edit] your post to fix the odd looking copy/paste errors (or maybe the site glitched and didn't properly accept your edits before posting?) Also, please explain what a "normal gud 10" globe is - that's not a bulb reference I'm familiar with.